# How do I prepopulate an inline formset that is purely ImageFields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two models: `Profile` and `CredentialImage`.

I have implemented inlineformsets to allow the Profile to upload up to 5 maximum images(CredentialImage).

Currently, the images save to the database but they will not pre-populate when I revisit the update form, thus allowing the user to upload an unlimited amount of photos 5 at a time. Ideally, the same images saved to the database would pre-populate on the form as to limit the Profile to own and edit only 5 photos at a time.

From my understanding, I need to pass in the object to the page to pre-populate information, and I believe I'm doing just that by defining `get_object`.

Here are the two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile:profile_detail",
                       kwargs={"username": self.user})

class CredentialImage(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, default=None, 
        related_name='credentialimage')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=credential_photo_upload_loc)
```

The modelforms + initialization of the inlineformset_factory:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

class ProfileUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "introduction",
            "biography",
        ]

class CredentialImageForm(ModelForm):
    image = ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = CredentialImage
        fields = ['image', ]

CredentialImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Profile,
    CredentialImage, fields=('image', ), extra=4, max_num=4)
```

A class-based UpdateView for updating a Profile:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm
    template_name = 'profile/profile_edit.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['credential_image'] = CredentialImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            context['credential_image'] = CredentialImageFormSet()
        return context

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = self.kwargs.get('username')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_profile)
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):    
        data = self.get_context_data()
        formset = data['credential_image']
        if formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return redirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply an instance in your get_context_data method.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['credential_image'] = CredentialImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)
    else:
        context['credential_image'] = CredentialImageFormSet(instance=self.object)
    return context
```